# add a matplotlib mp4 plot to an existing matplotlib mp4

Tags: python-3.x, matplotlib, animation

Windows 10, python 3.6, matplotlib 3.3.2

I am trying to make a mp4 where a function plot would show and then another function plot would show on the top of it:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.animation as animation

# params
plt.rcParams['animation.ffmpeg_path'] = 'C:/xxx/ffmpeg.exe'

x_val = np.arange(0, 10)
lbl = ['sqr', 'cub', ]

# plot
fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(4,2))
line_2, = ax.plot([], [])
line_3, = ax.plot([], [])
ax.set_xlim(x_val.min(), x_val.max())
ax.set_ylim(0, 4)
ax.set_title('sqr & cub')
ax.legend(lbl, bbox_to_anchor=(1.3, 1))
plt.tight_layout()


def func_2(x):
    return x**(1/2)


def func_3(x):
    return x**(1/3)



X, Y_2, Y_3 = [], [], []
def animation_frame_2(x):
    X.append(x)
    Y_2.append(func_2(x))
    line_2.set_xdata(X)
    line_2.set_ydata(Y_2)
    return line_2,


def animation_frame_3(x):
    X.append(x)
    Y_2 = func_2(x_val)
    line_2.set_xdata(x_val)
    line_2.set_ydata(Y_2)
    Y_3.append(func_3(x))
    line_3.set_xdata(X)
    line_3.set_ydata(Y_3)
    return line_2, line_3,
   

anim = animation.FuncAnimation(fig,
                               func=animation_frame_2,
                               frames=x_val,
                               interval=100,
                               repeat=False)


anim = animation.FuncAnimation(fig,
                               func=animation_frame_3,
                               frames=x_val,
                               interval=100,
                               repeat=False)
plt.show()
```

My intent is to have the first  plot to show as an animation then, fix it and draw the second plot show as an animation on the top of the fixed first plot. Hence create some progression as opposed to both plot lines progressing together.

I was expecting to see: first the sqr plot progressing across all x_val individually, then on the top of showing the entire sqr plot, the cub plot progressing across all x_val individually.
Instead, I am getting only the plot where sqr is plotted entirely and cub progresses across x_val.

Would love to have a few hints on how to work this, thanks.

Comment: Just make one animation that animates both sets of lines

Comment: Thanks.  However, my intent is to have the first  plot to show as an animation then, fix it and draw the second plot show as an animation on the top of the fixed first plot. Hence create some progression.  
Your proposal would merely show the 2 plot line updating at the same time... not what i am trying to achieve,

Comment: After x frames, stop animating the first set of artists and start animating the others.

Comment: That's what I am trying to do, yes.  But how would I do that please?

Comment: In your animation function check the value of x.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Staggering the data is what I resolved doing. This could be optimized. Hoping it will help someone.
Cheers

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.animation as animation

# params
plt.rcParams['animation.ffmpeg_path'] = 'C:/xxx/ffmpeg.exe'

x_val = np.linspace(0, 10, 10)

# plot
fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(4,2))
line_sqr, = ax.plot([], [], label='square')
line_cub, = ax.plot([], [], label='cube')
ax.set_xlim(x_val.min(), x_val.max())
ax.set_ylim(0, 4)
ax.set_title('square & cube')
ax.legend(bbox_to_anchor=(1.3, 1))
plt.tight_layout()


def func_sqr(x):
    return x**(1/2)

    
def func_cub(x):
    return x**(1/3)



x, X, Y_sqr, Y_cub = 0, [], [], []

def animation_frame(i):
    global x, X, Y_sqr, Y_cub

    if i % len(x_val) == 0:
        x = 0
        X, Y_sqr, Y_cub = [], [], []

    X.append(x_val[x])

    if i // len(x_val) == 0:  # first animation episode --> sqr
        Y_sqr.append(func_sqr(x_val[x]))
        line_sqr.set_xdata(X)
        line_sqr.set_ydata(Y_sqr)

        line_cub.set_xdata(None)
        line_cub.set_ydata(None)

    if i // len(x_val) == 1:  # second animation episode --> cube
        Y_sqr = func_sqr(x_val)
        line_sqr.set_xdata(x_val)
        line_sqr.set_ydata(Y_sqr)

        Y_cub.append(func_cub(x))
        line_cub.set_xdata(X)
        line_cub.set_ydata(Y_cub)
        
    x += 1
    return line_sqr, line_cub,


   
anim = animation.FuncAnimation(fig,
                               func=animation_frame,
                               frames=range(0, 2*len(x_val)),
                               interval=50,
                               repeat=False)



plt.show()
```